# Why Sql Profiler reports some queries as SQL:BatchCompleted and some as RPC:Completed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

[image]

The first query `SELECT TOP 1 name FROM SiteMast...` is issued using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`.

The third query `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT n.Nam...` is issued using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync`, which should be the same.

I am pretty certain the async vs blocking is not the factor here - tested on a small sample:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sql
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sync();
            Async().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static void Sync()
        {
            using (var c = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=test;trusted_connection=true"))
            {
                c.Open();
                using (var cmd = c.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Namespace,ClientId FROM Client";
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{reader.GetString(0)}\t{reader.GetInt32(1)}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private static async Task Async()
        {
            using (var c = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=dftest;uid=***;pwd=***"))
            {
                await c.OpenAsync();
                using (var cmd = c.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Namespace,ClientId FROM Client";
                    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{reader.GetString(0)}\t{reader.GetInt32(1)}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code generates two SQL:BatchCompleted events.

My question - what causes some ADO.NET queries to be reported as `SQL:BatchCompleted` and some as `RPC:Completed`?

Comment: Does that answer your question?

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34484/difference-between-sql-batch-statement-and-rpc

Comment: I saw that one before posting my question - it does not.

Comment: It does contain a relevant piece: RPC" vs "batch" is the TDS execution mode that ADO.NET (or any SQL Server client) uses. When a plain SQL statement with no parameters is executed, we use a "batch". When a stored-proc is executed, we use RPC (this is not the same as RPC as the stand-alone network remote procedure call, we just happen to call this mode RPC in TDS (the SQL Server network protocol)). Also, if you execute a batch with parameter, we actually use a stored-proc called sp_executesql, and pass the SQL statement itself and the rest of the parameters to it, so it also shows up as RPC.

Comment: @Viking I missed that part (too much text in the original answer). Please arrange your comment as an answer and quote the relevant information so I could credit you.

Comment: copied n thanks :)